# How do I call a templatized operator()()?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, operators

I have a struct that looks something like:

```
struct foo_t
{
    template <std::size_t x, std::size_t y>
    std::size_t operator()() const
    { return /*something dealing with x and y*/; }
};
```

The definition seems to compile fine, but how do I call it? I can't seem to get anything past the compiler:

```
foo_t foo;
foo<3, 3>(); // ERROR: Compiler seems to think I'm asking for "foo < 3 ..."
```

Comment: You probably don't want to do that... using `operator` overloading usually helps with the syntax, but if you need to provide the template arguments it is going to make your code uglier.

Comment: Probably a typo, but right now your syntax is a bit wrong. It needs to be `ret_type operator()()` (or the second pair of parens can declare some argument types). Under the circumstances, I'd wonder why you're doing this at all though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's ugly, but..,

```
foo_t foo;
foo.operator()<3, 3>();
```

<sub>[Online demo.](http://ideone.com/1h377)</sub>

Comment: +1. Every time I see a snippet like this I feel sorry for the compiler implementors :-) It's not the template that gets me so much as the fact that the string `()<3, 3>()` has a valid context.

Comment: @Cameron I usually say that there is some magic involved in compiling templates :P