# C++ function objects with explicit template parameters

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I have a function object with an explicit(ie non-deduced) template parameter defined like this:

```
struct foo
{
    template<class T>
    T operator()() const
    {
        return 5;
    }
};

foo bar = {};
```

When I try to call it like this:

```
int main()
{
    int i = bar<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compile error. Is there no way to call the function object with a template parameter like a regular function? I really need to have it as a function object. Making a free function is not really an option for me(or at least, it is a very messy option).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call a templatized operator()()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105060/how-do-i-call-a-templatized-operator)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't call it like that. You need to use the `operator()` syntax:

```
int i = bar.operator()<int>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a trick with the conversion operator like this:

```
struct foo
{
  struct inner {
    template <typename T> operator T() const { return 5; }
  };
  inner operator()() const { return inner(); }
};

foo bar = {};
int main()
{
  int i = bar(); // implicit
  auto x = static_cast<int>(bar()); // "explicit" template parameter
}
```

I think a syntax exactly like `bar<int>()` is impossible.

Comment: That would only work the template parameter was used in the return type, like in my example, but I have a need to use them with function objects that don't use the template parameter in the return type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simplify your solution as this:

```
template<class T>
struct foo
{
        T operator()() const
        {
            return 5;
        }
};

foo<int> bar = {};

int main()
{
    int i = bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now it's possible to write `int i=bar;` which you probably don't want.