# How do I call operator() on "this"?

Tags: c++

I have a member function which needs to call operator() on the class instance (this), and I could not guess at the right syntax.
I tried

```
  this();
  *this();
  this->();
  this->operator();
```

and a few other things, but the error messages are not very informative, so I dont know what am I doing wrong.

The closest I found on SE: [How do I call a templatized operator()()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105060/how-do-i-call-a-templatized-operator)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`(*this)(/*parameters*/)`

is probably the clearest way.

Comment: Attention: dont forget the brackets around *this , so it must be (*this).

Comment: @Kostas: brackets -> parentheses

Answer (score 8):

Answer: use

```
 this->operator()();
```

Explanation:

- **this** is a pointer,
- **->** is the right way to access a member function on a pointer to a class,
- **operator()** is the name of the function,
- the second **()** is the empty argument list of the function.
  Thus, the first pair of brackets is part of the functions's name and the second pair is to provide the argument(s), which might not be empty in general.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a correct way to call the operator().

Answer (score 5):

I propose an example (test method):

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    int operator()(int index)
    {
        return index + 1;
    }
    int test()
    {
        // call to operator ()
        return this->operator()(5);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A obj;
    std::cout << obj.test() << std::endl;
    std::cout << obj(7) << std::endl;
    std::cout << obj.operator()(9) << std::endl;
}
```